# What would be a characteristic-$p$ analogue for $C^{\infty}$-fiber bundles?

Tags: characteristic-p, ag.algebraic-geometry

I'd like to know a notion for a morphism between algebraic varieties in characteristic $p$ that plays the role of a $C^{\infty}$-fiber bundle. It should be, in particular, flat. I'm not assuming the morphism to be smooth; e.g. a family of nodal curves $X_t$ with $p_a=2$ and such that the $j$-invariant  of the normalizations $\widetilde{X}_t$ is not constant in $t,$ would certainly qualify.

**Motivation:** If $f:X\to Y$ is a proper morphism of complex algebraic varieties, then by Morse theory, there exists a "stratification of $f";$ in particular, over each stratum of $Y,\ f$ is a $C^{\infty}$-fiber bundle. I wonder if this could be true in char. $p,$ but the first thing is to have an analogous notion.

Comment: Hey Shenghao, maybe check out this MO question... http://mathoverflow.net/questions/49759/definition-of-fiber-bundle-in-algebraic-geometry

Comment: Thanks, Kevin. I had a question about the suggested definition, and have just posted it there.